# CSS Float Left to Line Up

Tags: css

[(JSFIddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/4) Using `float : left`, we can achieve this:
[image]

```
<ul>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="half">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="half">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="half">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="half">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
li{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#eee;
    display:inline-block !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
li.half{
    width:50px; height:50px
}
```

But, how can we achieve this? **(By staying in this HTML markup - that's why HTML is not tagged!!)**

[image]

I notice that in the first case, the second line of small images is a new line. But, any ways to go through this?

Comment: Maybe look at sub listing your smaller block

Comment: @JonP, that could help. But, I added a part in answer `by not changing markup`. It is important beacause these list load from JSON or some data structure which carries the class of image. In short, they are not hard-coded. And usign PHP if-else and finding if next 4 elements are small or not is not simple. In addition, I might have a wider image equal to half width but full length

Comment: E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/5/

Comment: @JonP, Is there a way out without changing the HTML markup? I could use even jQuery if that would help :)

Comment: why do you have php checking html elements opposed to javascript?

Comment: Ahhh OK, gotcha. Might be worth investigating: http://masonry.desandro.com/. It may be overkill or it may be exactly what you need. I doubt there is a "pure" css solution.

Comment: There indeed IS a pure CSS solution, but it will have to be customized to work in all possible cases. And it's going to be quite some code (and headache, if the number of permutations as of what can follow what in the markup gets big)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve what you're looking for, no matter where the 4 smaller items appear in your list nor how many groups of them you have and without the need for any additional markup by using [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and a bit of trickery involving margins.

**UPDATE:** Added the ability to have a group of 3 small items

Here's a very quick proof of concept for you, with the last 4 rules being the most important to what we're doing here. The only caveat with the below, as it stands, is that you can't have a group of small items immediately following another group of small items.

```css
ul{
    font-size:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:550px;
}
li{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
li.small{
    background:green;
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 10px 10px -110px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small){
    margin-left:55px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 10px 10px 0;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small){
    margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

To explain what's going on above in those last 4 rules:

1. Select every item of class `small` that is immediately preceded by at least two other items of class `small`. Move them down, using a top `margin` by the height of one small item plus the margin size - 45+10=55px. Move them to the right, using a negative left `margin` by the width of 2 small items plus double the margin size - 2*(45+10)=110px.
2. To "reset" the margins when a group only has 3 small items, we introduce the [negation pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to select every item that is preceded by at least three items of class `small` but does not itself have the small class. Using `margin-left`, we move that left by the width of one small item plus the margin size - 45+10=55px.
3. Next, we need to override the margins for every fourth item of class `small`. Were we not to do so, the layout would be completely messed up as each fourth item also matches the first selector. For this one, we just need to move it down again by the height of one small item plus the margin size so, as in step 1, we set the top `margin` to 55px. No need to set the left `margin` here as, by using a negative margin on the preceding item, this one shifts to the right with it.
4. And, finally, we need to remove the `margin-left` from every item that is not `.small` and is preceded by at least four items that are.

---

**UPDATE 27/05/16:** So, I finally came back to this and modified it to have the ability to have a any number of small items up to 8 grouped together. I haven't had a chance to document the new rules yet and there are a couple of limitations in that a group of small items must be contained to a single row and a row can not end with a single small item or a group of 5. You can already see the code is becoming pretty unwieldy and will only get worse as you add the ability to have more than 8 small items grouped together.

```css
ul{
    background:#000;
    font-size:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
    width:550px;
}
li{
    border:1px solid #fff;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
li.small{
    background:green;
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    background:blue;
}
li.small:first-child+li:not(.small),li:not(.small)+li.small+li:not(.small),li.small:first-child+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small),li:not(.small)+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small){
    margin-left:55px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 10px 10px -110px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small){
    margin-left:55px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 10px 10px 0;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li:not(.small){
    margin-left:0;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin-top:0;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 65px 10px -110px;
}
li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small+li.small{
    margin:55px 10px 10px -55px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
    <li class="small"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will my code suffice as is or is there a possibility that you will have 2 or more groups of 4 small items in succession?

Comment: Yes, I might have. what I noticed is if I have 3 items in a grid of smalls, only 2 are shown. http://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/11/ Also, as you said, when there are 4+ items, they line up in second line. I will have max 2 boxes ( 8 items ) lined up at a place.

Comment: They're all there, it's just that the second one is "hiding" under the next red one ;) As I see it, though, accommodating a group of less than or more than 4 would be beyond the current scope of the question. That said, I will look into the code necessary for a group of 4 that follows a group of 4 when I have a minute over the weekend.

Comment: Typical! As soon as I get up and leave my computer, I come up with a possible solution for the group of 3. I don't want to post it, though, until I can properly test it, which I can't do on my phone, unfortunately.

Comment: Well waiting for great ideas ! ;)

Comment: Managed to get JSFiddle to work on my phone so here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/7sw8kg2y/ Note the 2 new rules that make use of the negation pseudo selector. Will update my answer when I'm back in front of a computer.

Comment: This is just what I proposed this morning in my edit.

Comment: @connexo, right. But, please look at your solution variation with less than or more than 4 small elements.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/12/ Both have 8 .small elements now. Or did I not get what you need?

Comment: Apologies for the delay but I've now updated my answer with the necessary CSS for a group of 3 small items.

Comment: @tika, after all this time I've updated my answer to give you the ability to have a group of up to 8 small items.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution to this is to restructure your markup. You need to create a new floating context (if you go float, which I recommend due to white-space related problems if you go inline-block) for the smaller list items, so you can end the float on the third item (to create a "new line") without destroying the float of the bigger list items.

Another approach to solve this would be flex box model, but this is way more difficult to learn and does not work cross-browser.

```css
ul,
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left
}
ul {
  width: 400px
}
ul,
h3 {
  clear: both
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
}
.sublist > li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
.sublist li:nth-of-type(3) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1:</h3>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sublist">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Example 2:</h3>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sublist">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Check this (identical) fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/3/

Edit: This is a working solution which does not require any markup changes:

```css
ul,
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left
}
ul,
h3 {
  clear: both
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.half {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.half+.half+.half {
  left: -100px;
  top: 50px;
}
.half+.half+.half+.half+li {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1:</h3>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
</ul>

<h3>Example 2:</h3>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li class="half"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/6/

Comment: well, that's not a bad approach. But, re-sizing is not what I am looking for. Just take it as that I cannot re-size.

Comment: What do you mean "re-sizing"?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean, without changing markup. Does that help? Because, I cannot change markup very easily. And there are a bunch of scattered sizes. Not just half or full.

Comment: This (kind of tricky implementation) fixes your issue. It will, though, have to be extended to work in the case of for example 8 .half items following each other in the mark-up.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/6/

https://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/6/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to target 2nd and 3rd li using :nth-child(N) selector and make its float to right.

Your css will look like:

```
 ul,li{
    margin:0;padding:0;display:block;
}
ul{width:450px}
ul,h3{clear:both}
li{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#eee;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
li.half{
    width:50px; height:50px;

}
.ex1 li:nth-child(2), .ex1 li:nth-child(3){
   float: right;    
}
```

Check [updated fiddle please](http://jsfiddle.net/Lok8oo6b/9/)